# Cron job using database results

Tags: mysql, variables, ffmpeg, cron

I need help in creating a cron job script. Basically, I want to grab the next scheduled item and run it through ffmpeg to stream. This would be the mysql query (I'm using PHP variables to indicate what should go there - I don't actually know how variables work in cron jobs):

```
SELECT show.file FROM show, schedule
WHERE channel = 1 AND start_time <= $current_time;
```

This would be the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i $file http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed.ffm
```

How would I create a cron job to execute these commands?

Comment: Does your query return one file?

Comment: It does, the interface will update the old entry if there is one when a new one is scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all IMHO you don't need to pass current time to your select statement, just use `CURRENT_TIME`

```
SELECT `show.file` 
  FROM show, schedule 
 WHERE channel = 1 AND start_time <= CURRENT_TIME;
```

*Depending on your actual table's DDL **you might need** to do some conversion to correctly compare time values.*

Assuming that your query correct and returns **ONLY ONE filename** you can execute the query with mysql, output the result into predefined file and use `&&` to chain `ffmpeg` command

```
mysql -u user -ppassword dbname -sN -e \
 "SELECT show.file \
 FROM show, schedule \
 WHERE channel = 1 AND start_time <= CURRENT_TIME" > /tmp/cur_show_file && \
 ffmpeg -re -i /tmp/cur_show_file http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed.ffm
```

Comment: Small amendment: I actually had to replace /tmp/cur_show_file in the ffmpeg command with \`cat /tmp/cur_show_file\`. Other than that, it worked perfectly.